# Get the value of this array using JSONObject class

Tags: java, json

How can I get the value of device (SE_S2) or status using JSONObject class?

```
String body = '{"device":"SE_S2","status":"1","time":"1524737618.66301","status":"ON"} '
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(body);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It won't work**, because you have a duplicate key ("status"). If you remove that, you'd be able to get the device by doing:

```
String body = "{\"device\":\"SE_S2\",\"status\":\"1\",\"time\":\"1524737618.66301\"}";
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(body);
System.out.println(root.get("device"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:-

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(body);
String device = root.get("device").toString();
```

Comment: It's not working for him because of a duplicate key in the JSON structure

Answer (score 0):

For json {\"device\":\"SE_S2\",\"status\":\"1\",\"time\":\"1524737618.66301\"}

1. To get "SE_S2" you can use root.get("device")
2. To get "1" you can use root.get("status")

Note that you have multiple element with the same key 'status' which is not allowed.